# Dictionary and table section issues ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsdictionary

i'm trying to figure out why the sections of my table only load the last array data from the dictionary. Ex. If i have 3 section and my array data have size of 3, 5, 7, all my 3 sections will have 7 rows (the last one). Below is my code:

Load data

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *) Carrega_musica_por_artista: (NSString *) nome_artista {
    NSMutableDictionary *artista = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    dados = [NSMutableArray new];
    [self Abre_conexao];
    query = [db executeQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select m.nome_cantor FROM Musicas_info as m INNER JOIN Campo_pesquisa as cp ON m.id_musica = cp.id_musica where cp.artista like '%%%@%%' GROUP BY cp.artista ORDER BY cp.artista ASC", nome_artista]];
    }
    if (query != nil) {
        while ([query next]) {
            query2 = [db executeQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select id_musica, nome_musica, nome_cantor, categoria, tom from Musicas_info where nome_cantor = \"%@\" and ativo <> 0 ORDER BY id_musica ASC", [query stringForColumn:@"nome_cantor"]]];
            if (query2 != nil) {
                [dados removeAllObjects];
                while ([query2 next]) {
                    Construtor_musica *musica_temp = [Construtor_musica new];
                    musica_temp.id_musica = [query2 intForColumn:@"id_musica"];
                    musica_temp.nome_musica = [query2 stringForColumn:@"nome_musica"];
                    musica_temp.autor_musica = [query2 stringForColumn:@"nome_cantor"];
                    musica_temp.categoria = [query2 stringForColumn:@"categoria"];
                    musica_temp.tom = [query2 intForColumn:@"tom"];
                    [dados addObject:musica_temp];
                }
            [artista setObject:dados forKey:[query stringForColumn:@"nome_cantor"]];
            }
        }
    }
    [db close];
    return artista;
}
```

Load on table

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dados_artista = [musica_db Carrega_musica_por_artista:self.textfield.text];
    NSArray *artistas = [[dados_artista allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *custom_cell = @"celula_musica";
    Celula_musica *cell = (Celula_musica *) [self.tabela_musica dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:custom_cell];
    if (!cell) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Celula_musica_ipad" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    Construtor_musica *mus_temp = [[dados_artista objectForKey:[artistas objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell = [montagem_musica Montagem_celula:mus_temp celula:cell];
    return cell;
}

-(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [artistas objectAtIndex:section];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[dados_artista objectForKey:[artistas objectAtIndex:section]] count];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [artistas count];
}
```

Comment: You are only allocating one `dados` array and continually reusing it, this means that each key in your dictionary is associated with the *same* array instance. You need to allocate a new `dados` array inside the while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only allocating one `dados` array and continually reusing it, this means that each key in your dictionary is associated with the same array instance. You need to allocate a new `dados` array inside the while loop.

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *) Carrega_musica_por_artista: (NSString *) nome_artista {
    NSMutableDictionary *artista = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [self Abre_conexao];
    query = [db executeQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select m.nome_cantor FROM Musicas_info as m INNER JOIN Campo_pesquisa as cp ON m.id_musica = cp.id_musica where cp.artista like '%%%@%%' GROUP BY cp.artista ORDER BY cp.artista ASC", nome_artista]];
    }
    if (query != nil) {
        while ([query next]) {
            query2 = [db executeQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select id_musica, nome_musica, nome_cantor, categoria, tom from Musicas_info where nome_cantor = \"%@\" and ativo <> 0 ORDER BY id_musica ASC", [query stringForColumn:@"nome_cantor"]]];
            if (query2 != nil) {
                dados = [NSMutableArray new];
                while ([query2 next]) {
                    Construtor_musica *musica_temp = [Construtor_musica new];
                    musica_temp.id_musica = [query2 intForColumn:@"id_musica"];
                    musica_temp.nome_musica = [query2 stringForColumn:@"nome_musica"];
                    musica_temp.autor_musica = [query2 stringForColumn:@"nome_cantor"];
                    musica_temp.categoria = [query2 stringForColumn:@"categoria"];
                    musica_temp.tom = [query2 intForColumn:@"tom"];
                    [dados addObject:musica_temp];
                }
                [artista setObject:dados forKey:[query stringForColumn:@"nome_cantor"]];
            }
        }
    }
    [db close];
    return artista;
}
```

Comment: I thought that only cleaning the array was enough...Ty @Paulw11